# Android fragment view with vertical scrollbar and left and right swipe gesture detection

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am implementing a simple jokes app with a functionality of swipe left and right to see the next or the previous joke. A joke could be long and thus I need the scrollbar on the textview. However, it looks like the ontouch listener and the scrollbar are messing with each other and after scrolling the swipe does not work. Any idea?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFF"
                tools:context="com.bontututu.bontu.JokeFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0px"
        android:layout_y="25px"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtJoke"
            style="@style/jokeText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtSwipeLeft"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtSwipeRight"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""/>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSwipeRight"
        style="@style/swipeIndicatorStyle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="☛"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSwipeLeft"
        style="@style/swipeIndicatorStyle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="☚"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

part of the fragment code is below.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_joke, container, false);
        _textViewJoke = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtJoke);
        _textViewLeftSwipeIndicator = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSwipeLeft);
        _textViewRightSwipeIndicator = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSwipeRight);
        _mainScrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAreaScroller);
        getJokes();
        displayCurrentJoke();
        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity())
        {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight()
            {
                _mainScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                if (_jokes != null)
                {
                    _currentJokeIndex--;
                    displayCurrentJoke();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft()
            {
                _mainScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                if (_jokes != null)
                {
                    _currentJokeIndex++;
                    displayCurrentJoke();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeTop()
            {
                _mainScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeBottom()
            {
                _mainScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating your swipeview??

Comment: I also had this scenario once and then I used view pager for swipe view

Comment: use viewpager for swipe left right